Can I put an assertion in a character class in regex?
I want to write a Regex that matches strings that contain letters, spaces and numbers followed by dots. The numbers can appear anywhere in the string and there can be multiple. For example:
Foo            -> Match
Foo Bar        -> Match
Foo 1 Bar      -> No Match
Foo 1. Bar     -> Match
Foo 11. Bar    -> Match
1. Foo 11. Bar -> Match

I know that I can match letters and spaces with [a-zA-Z ]+ and numbers followed by a dot with \d+(?=\.). But when I insert the latter into the former it matches all numbers, as well as the literal characters '+', '(', '?', '=', '.' and ')'.
Is there a way to achieve this?

No, it should be done like ^(?:\d+\.|[a-zA-Z ])*$

What about empty strings? If these are allowed, unrolled: ^[a-zA-Z ]*(?:\d+\.[a-zA-Z ]*)*$

Character classes are meant to match characters, you cannot put zero-width assertions into character classes. Notice how \b loses its word boundary meaning inside a character class and starts matching backspace characters (in most regex flavors at least).
In this case, you can match zero or more occurrences of either one or more digits with a dot right after or the characters you allow:
^(?:\d+\.|[a-zA-Z ])*$

See the regex demo. If an empty string is not allowed, replace * with + before the $ anchor.
Details:

^ - start of string
(?:\d+\.|[a-zA-Z ])* - zero or more repetitions of

\d+\. - one or more digits and then a .
[a-zA-Z ] - an ASCII letter or a regular space


$ - end of string.

In Java code, no need to use ^ and $ with String.matches():
text.matches("(?:\\d+\\.|[a-zA-Z ])*")

